# Minimum variance of binary matrix

Tags: python

I have a matrix of 0 and 1, example:

```
X = 
[[1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
```

In each row, choose only an '1' and leave orthers become 0, to get the same number of '1' in each colunm. Basically, minimum variance after get sum by columns.
Example: From X above, the answer is:

```
Y = 
[[1, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
```

Each column in Y have a '1'. Y choose 1st '1' from row 1 of X, choose 2nd '1' in index 4 from row 2,.... X can have any size.

How can i do that?
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do your `Y` matrices always need to be constructed from existing `X` matrices? If your end goal is just `Y` matrices with this property then a very easy solution would be to shuffle the rows of the identity matrix. What determines which solution you pick (there are multiple for your example)?

Comment: Yes, Y always need to be constructed from X. In my example, Y choose 1st '1' from row 1 of X, choose 2nd '1' in index 4 from row 2 of X,...

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: what follows is a brute force technique which finds every "solution". It does not work for non-square arrays because OP's problem is vague on how non-square arrays should be treated. The technique I have in mind for finding a random solution is just a simple backtracking algorithm over `idxs`, which I may get around to tomorrow if somebody else doesn't come up with something better.

Here's a brute force solution which takes the cartesian product of the column indices where there is a one for each row:

```py
import itertools
import numpy as np


x = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0],
              [1, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 1, 1]])


n = x.shape[1]
rows, cols = np.argwhere(x).T
idxs = np.split(cols, np.unique(rows, return_index=True)[1][1:])
col_idxs = [t for t in itertools.product(*idxs) if len(set(t)) == n]
row_idxs = np.arange(n)
```

Showing all solutions for this particular `X`:

```py
for t in col_idxs:
    z = np.zeros_like(x)
    z[row_idxs, t] = 1
    print(f"{z}\n")
```

Output:

```py
[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 1 0 0]]

[[1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 1 0 0]]

[[0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]]

[[0 1 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]]

[[0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 0 0]]

[[0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: X can be any size, not square matrix. My X.shape is (744, 15), and i use ur code but it take a long time (more than 2m)

Comment: Right well like I said, this is a brute force solution that generates a cartesian product with a size, in the worst case (an array of all 1s), of `num_columns**num_rows`. To reiterate, my code is finding EVERY possible `Y` exhibiting the property you want, given a matrix `X`.

Comment: For non-square matrices, you're going to have a lot of columns (if wide) or rows (if tall) with all zeros, since obviously non-square matrices aren't full-rank. Or is selecting multiple `1`s from a given row allowed (in the case of wide matrices)? In the case of tall matrices (rows > columns), you will not be able to satisfy your desired property while also ensuring that *every row* has a `1`.

Comment: How about a new X by double last X to shape (8,4). Can you modify you code?

Comment: `x = 
[[1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 0],
[1, 0, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 1, 1]]`